# How to read files in javascript, for older browsers

Tags: javascript, html

I have implemented File reader using HTML 5 FILE API, i followed the example below:

http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/read-text-files-using-the-javascript-filereader.html#fbid=-7qrc-_cRXo

Now my requirement has changed and i need to support older browsers, not really sure how to do this.

any ideas?

Comment: Check this link for filereader api browser support:  http://caniuse.com/filereader ... and for older browser you very likely will need flash and/or silverlight

Comment: What are your requirements? Can you delegate the file operations to the backend instead?

Answer (score -2):

The only way to read a file in older versions of javascript is using cookies. It is a security issue.

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: How would you do that?

Comment: @putvande you simply ask nicely a cookie to go find a file!